# Pulling text to right hand side of page

Tags: html, css

I'm new to this kind of stuff and I am wondering if someone can help me. If you visit [www.ebsmotherwell.org.uk/index.php](http://www.ebsmotherwell.org.uk/index.php) you will see the website that is currently being developed.

I'm trying to move this piece of code to the right-hand side.

```
<strong>REACHING OUR LOCAL COMMUNITY</strong>
```

While I have tried to modify the CSS, I'm not able to target that specific element.

At the top of the page, you will see the logo and then next to it "Reaching our local community" - I want to be able to position that about a third of the way over, so essentially approximately 30px from the right-hand side. I still want it kept in the middle like it is at the moment and if possible the same colour as the navigation bar and a little bigger.

Anything I have tried, such a pull-right or align right doesn't work properly. It goes onto a new line or goes to the top right-hand side.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Don't link to external sites and instead post the code in the question. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, and explain the specific problem in a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replace:**

```
<strong>REACHING OUR LOCAL COMMUNITY</strong>
```

**To:**

```
<strong class="someText">REACHING OUR LOCAL COMMUNITY</strong>
```

**Add CSS to that class:**

```
.someText {
   float:right;
   margin: 60px 30px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: I have tried the code and it worked but when I add the H2 tag onto it, the text disappeared and the navigation bar became bigger. Any suggestions? If you visit the link above you can see the result.

Comment: Yes, you need to move class="textright" to your H2 tag. Right now you're targeting the strong tag inside your H2 tag, that will not work. It should be <h2 class="textright"> @DAVIDSON-K

Comment: That works perfect, I added colour and bold text in CSS for it also. Now, it causes just one more issue but on the mobile view it make the navigation bar bigger. @cosmoonot

Comment: Also @cosmoonot - On the same page, the image that says Why Befriending is using the grid system but if I remove the thumbnail class, it becomes too big. Is there anyway to remove that thumbnail tag and keep it the same size as it looks just now and also scale down when on mobile and tablet devices?

Comment: @DAVIDSON-K why do you want to remove the class?

Comment: It adds as rectangular shape around the image. I would prefer the image to be the same size as it is and scale according to the device it is on just without the thumbnail class.

Comment: @DAVIDSON-K Just remove the border from .img-thumbnail class. border:1px solid #ddd. Remove that.

Comment: Where do I remove this and am I able to only apply it to that one image? I tried to start a chat with you but I don't have enough reputation as I'd like to ask you more and perhaps even some paid work if you do it.

Comment: @DAVIDSON-K Check bootstrap.min.css and search for .img-thumbnail. Sure, what your email?

Comment: keiran.davidson@motherwellelim.org.uk